# How to provide service that hosts user data without violating user privacy?

Tags: wordpress, security, hosting, privacy, data-storage

I'd like to start a website that provides users with photos editing/storing experience. The initial idea is that the user has his own account where we store the edited photos and some settings. I'm am a WordPress web developer and when I try to consider how to build such a website in WordPress I don't really understand how to provide such a services without having access to user photos. My idea was to create a custom post type and save it with the user as an author. But as an admin of the website, I will have access to all the created/saved photos and I would like to build it in a way that I don't have it. Is it possible?

I've used previously the app to write a diary that saved the data to my Google Drive and if I understand correctly, it never had access to my files.

So my question is: what are the best practices to build such a resource? Is it normal to have access to all of your user photos if you provide such a platform?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, as you will use WordPress and you are the developer you will always have access to the data of everything.

You will always have a way of knowing which data is from user or which data belongs to another user.

You have two options to do this, but this will take some development work:

**1** - You must recreate the way WordPress works where the user is not related to an email and not private data that can relate to the user.
Example: You ask the user to register only that only asks for a hash that can be any word, number, or any other information and a second field would be the password.

With this in the backend you get this two information and do some kind of hash I'll give the example using md5 but do not use it.

After that join these two data and this will be the user.

and to login the user needs to repeat this information and will be within the platform. With this you will be able to maintain the anonymity of the user and will not know who the user is.

In this option you will have for each hash and password a different user :)

But I recommend not using wordpress if you choose this option. You can use a framework like CodeIgniter for example which is super simple.

[image]

**2** - The second way would be to use the normal wp User, not worrying about who the user is and their information. But one way to keep photo information "anonymous" is to generate a unique hash with each user and have some way of relating the user to it.

Example: When uploading a file to edit it will generate a passkey, you must warn the user that when they want to edit this photo or view they will need to type it into an input. With this you will not know which information is from which user. but it requires extra work for the user

---

This way you will always have anonymity of user information. I hope I helped you somehow.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and suggestions! I will check the CodeIgniter framework. It looks like the WP may not be suitable for the task.